# Error message when uploading image to do prediction using keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

****Error message when uploading image to make prediction****

> ValueError: Input 0 of layer block1_conv1 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 3 but received input with shape [None, 224, 224, 4]

****Code handling/pre-processing image****

```py
def model_predict(img, model):
    img = img.resize((224, 224))

    # Preprocessing the image
    x = image.img_to_array(img)
    x = np.true_divide(x, 255)
    x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)

    # Be careful how your trained model deals with the input
    # otherwise, it won't make correct prediction!
    x = preprocess_input(x, mode='tf')

    preds = model.predict(x)
    return preds
```

****Output of training session****

```py
flow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
Compiling model...
Model has 14716227 parameters
Model: "model"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, 224, 224, 3)]     0         
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 224, 224, 64)      1792      
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 224, 224, 64)      36928     
_________________________________________________________________
block1_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 112, 112, 64)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 112, 112, 128)     73856     
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 112, 112, 128)     147584    
_________________________________________________________________
block2_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 56, 56, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 56, 56, 256)       295168    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 56, 56, 256)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 56, 56, 256)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 28, 28, 256)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 28, 28, 512)       1180160   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 28, 28, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 28, 28, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 14, 14, 512)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 7, 7, 512)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_Mean (TensorFlow [(None, 512)]             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (None, 512)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 3)                 1539      
======================================
```

Answer (score 1):

If You want to work with the batch training and testing part, you should definitely checkout  the `ImageDataGenerator`. Not even does it help you creating the batches, also helps you with the Image Augmentation (art to make your model robust). It gives you a parameter as `rescaling` and `preprocess_function` which you can easily set to `rescale=1/255., preprocessing_function=preprocess_input,`

You code is having problems with the Channels part. If you're using the `channels_last`, then it has been trained on the `(batch,width,height,3)` 3 channels data and when you are trying to pass the data for testing, it is showing error.

In this case, you should remove the alpha channel. Please check  [ImageData Generator](https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/). there is a parameter in all of the `flow_from_dataframe` , `flow_from_directory` and `flow` as `color_mode='rgb` which is default.

Else, you can open your images as

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open(img_path).convert('RGB') # get RGB PNG image
img = np.array(img) # Convert to numpy array
img = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0) # add an extra dimension for batch
```

then You can apply your `preprocess_function`

```
img = preprocess_input(img, mode='tf')

preds = model.predict(img)
return preds
```

**Note: You should use the `reshape` or `expand_dims` method of `numpy` for creating an extra batch axis  if you're working with single image as the `Keras` always expect a batch.**

Comment: If you found the answer helpful, please do upvote and acept  it too so that any newcomer will see the answer first and won't have to look at all the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Because you try to feed the model with 4 channel image. Please take firts 3 channel after convert image to array.

```
Preprocessing the image
x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = img[:, :, :3]
x = np.true_divide(x, 255)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
```

Comment: I think throwing off the 4th axis should not be used. This depends on the color space you use. If the `RGBA` is in pre-multiplied color-space and is semi-transparent, you need to divide out alpha to get the correct `RGB` color. If the color is in non pre-multiplied color-space, then you can just discard the alpha channel.

Comment: File "app.py", line 89, in predict_backend
    preds = model_predict(img, model)
  File "app.py", line 51, in model_predict
    x = image[:,:,:3]
TypeError: 'module' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Please change the x = image[:, :, :3] to x = img[:, :, :3].

Comment: I am getting following error    Image' object is not subscriptable